# Find Confidence Intervall in temporal dissaggregation

Tags: r, confidence-interval, temporal

I use the package "tempdisagg" to disaggregate a yearly time series into quarterly values with the maximum-log-likelihood method by Chow-Lin. When I do this with JDemetra+ I can generate confidence intervals for the estimated quarterly values. It it possible to get these confidence intervals using this package or otherwise in R?

Example Code:

```
DataY <- ts(c(rnorm(10)), start = 1998, frequency = 1)
DataQ <- ts(c(rnorm(40)), start=1998, frequency = 1)
            
ML <- td(DataY~DataQ + 0, conversion = "sum", to = "quarterly", method= "chow-lin-maxlog")
predict(ML)
```

Additionally I'm wondering if it is possible to split the resulting quarterly values in the "regression" and "smoothing" or benchmarking part of the calculation (also like in JDemetra+).